# Unable to run pylinter, set python interpreter in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio, linter

I've seen a few questions opened on Stack Overflow and the dedicated VS Code Git, but all of the solutions have revolved on reinstallations and after trying this on the Python extension and VS Code itself multiple times with necessary restarts I'm still nowhere nearer to a solution. Linter was performing fine up until a few days ago when it seems to have broken out of nowhere.

I've also noticed that "Go to Definition" isn't working (either the hotkey or menu navigation), so not sure if it's more a VS Code issue or issue with Python implementation, Intellisense seems to be working fine so leaning towards the latter.

## **Steps to Reproduce**

1) Cntrl + Shift + P to open command pallette

2a) "Python: Select Interpreter" - error "spawn EPERM")

2b) "Python: Select Linter" - error "command 'python.setLinter' not found"

## Versions

- Python 3.6.6
- Visual Studio Code 1.28
- Python extension 2018.9.0
- Windows 10

## User Settings

Tried setting an explicit path per suggestion, but again no dice.

```
{
"python.pythonPath": "C:/Users/saun89/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe",
"python.linting.pylintPath": "C:/Users/saun89/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/lib/site-packages/pylint",
}
```

I'll probably go ahead and open a ticket on the actual github (although this seems less a product issue and more an issue particular to myself), but wanted to check with the stack community to see if anyone else has had to troubleshoot something similar. At least until this gets inevitably voted down to oblivion being similar to some other existing questions.

## Extensive Error log (from developer tools)

Just in case they're helpful

```
notificationsAlerts.ts:40 Error: command 'python.setLinter' not found
    at t._tryExecuteCommand (commandService.ts:57)
    at commandService.ts:50
    at n.Class.derive._oncancel.then (winjs.base.js:1587)
    at t.executeCommand (commandService.ts:50)
    at t.run (actions.ts:220)
    at t.run (actions.ts:268)
    at commandsHandler.ts:309
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case you happen upon this question I did discover an answer here. Looks like the SPAWN EPERM error was in fact related to my running as a user rather than as an administrator. When I run VS Code as Administrator able to work with the command palette fine. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

You might also get this error when trying to use the search bar called `spawn EPERM` and the cause might be an antivirus.

since Visual Studio Code creates new process for search and other features (SPAWN corresponds to a new process creation) this can cause the Antivirus to stop that process and causing this error and the feature to no work.

solution: Create an exception in you antivirus for VS Code or disable the antivirus all together (if you feel like catching a virus)

Answer (score 1):

For setting the python interpreter question, temporary solution that worked for me on my Windows and Mac machines: use relative paths.

So in my case, instead of absolute path;

> "python.pythonPath": "/Users/userid/p3env/bin/python" (on Mac)
>   "python.pythonPath": "C:/Users/userid/p3env/bin/python" (on Windows)

I used relative path from my working folder;

> "python.pythonPath": "../../../../p3env/bin/python"

I haven't got any problem on my Ubuntu machine though. This issue affects many people I believe. It is also discussed in a few issues: [[3326]](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3326), [[3326]](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3535). It seems that it goes away in some update and comes back again in another somehow. Above workaround solution is not a very convenient way to do it so I hope there will be a permanent fix for this.

Comment: See below, at least in my case it was a matter of admin vs user permissions around SPAWN EPERM